# Can't find dependent assembly for VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, c#-to-vb.net

I'm having an issue with a VB.NET application(I haven't done much with VB.NET). I have one assembly that has a class that I need. There is also another assembly that the first one depends on.

Both the assemblies were written in C#.

In the first assembly I have a class called MyClass and in the second assembly I have MyDependentClass. MyClass references MyDependentClass.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private MyDependentClass myDepClass = null;
    public MyClass()
    {
        myDepClass = new MyDepClass();
    }
}
```

I am trying to use MyClass in both C# and VB.NET

C#

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
```

VB.NET

```
Dim myClass As MyClass = New MyClass()
```

On both the C# and VB.NET project I am only adding a reference to the assembly that has MyClass because that is the only one that I call directly from my application but the location of the reference of the assembly that has MyClass also has a copy of the assembly that has MyDependentClass.

As I said, in both cases I am referencing the same way for both C# and VB.NET. The C# version compiles without issue. The VB.NET version gives me an error that says "Reference required to assembly 'MyDependentAssembly' containing the type 'MyDependentClass'. Add one to your project."

Why does VB.NET require a reference to the dependent assembly when C# does not? Is there a way to fix this in VB.NET so it behaves the same as C#?

Comment: Hmya, doubtful snippet.  There is incredibly little point to argue with a compiler, it doesn't give a hoot about you yelling at it and in the end it always wins.  Add the reference.

Comment: @HansPassant In the actually implementation of the project adding the extra reference isn't allowed. My question is why does the VB.NET compiler complain when the C# compiler does not? Is there some reference setting that i am missing?

Comment: What happens if you turn off Option Explicit in VB?

Comment: @rism, thanks for the suggestion but it was Option Explicit was already off. I tried turning it on as well as Option Strict. No luck with either one.